# Сортировка при выводе данных

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть база ветеранов. Я вывожу всех. У каждого ветерана есть значение medal - это кол-во наград. Допустим максимум это 10 наград. Как мне выводить ветеранов в приоритетном порядке? Сначала у кого 10 медалей, потом 9 и так далее

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, fio, medal FROM people");

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдет оператор `ORDER BY`

Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

`SELECT id, fio, medal FROM people ORDER BY medal DESC`

Вот [здесь](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) подробнее

Comment: А если нужно вывести на первые позиции не только по медалям, но и по званиям, то это так делается ORDER BY level, medal ? `level - звание`